# What does "Windows Powershell compatibility (.net standard 2.0)" mean?

Tags: powershell, .net-standard

I was looking for a way to execute Powershell cmdlets in .net standard 2.0, but finally figured out that it's impossible because powershell is built with .net framework or .net core for powershell core.

During my researches I discovered this : https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/projects/4

If it's impossible to execute powershell in .net standard, what does this project stands for ?

Comment: You can think of. net standard as a contract, that defines which .net classes methods are available for your assembly.

Comment: Please see the second half of the dupe answer I linked to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[what is net standard](https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/net-standard-getting-started/) :

> .Net Standard is a specification which defines a set of APIs which the .Net platform has to implement. It is not another .Net platform though. You can only build libraries, not executables with it. On the following screenshot, you can see that .Net Standard contains APIs from the classic .Net framework, .Net core and Xamarin.

So you can build libraries against a standard that ensures it'll run either under net framework, or net core, or Xamarin. This is reasoned in the fact that the defined (in the standard) set of classes, interfaces, etc. are  implemented by before mentioned frameworks. With increasing net standard versions the amount of supportex classes, interfaces increases.

Since Powershell is not a library, you've to choose between Powershell 5.x ( using net framework) or Powershell 6 (= using net core). Since you can invoke C# Libraries from Powershell, a library implementing net standard can be invoked from Powershell 5 and from Powershell 6.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer you can call net libs from Powershell. Here is a example to use log4net with Powershell, https://www.vioreliftode.com/index.php/powershell-logging-using-apache-log4net/

Comment: Thanks to you I've now a better understanding of all of this. You can use .net standard classes in both powershell and powershell core, but can't use powershell/core with .net standard as it's used only for libraries. It's all clear now.